# how to mock mongodb connection or insert_one with async

Tags: mongodb, mocking, pytest

I have simple code,

```
async def create_document(
    conn: AsyncIOMotorClient, document: internal.Document
) -> internal.DocumentInDb:
    document_data = document.dict()
    document_added = await conn[database_name][documents_collection_name].insert_one(
        document_data
    )
    document_db = await conn[database_name][documents_collection_name].find_one(
        {"_id": document_added.inserted_id}
    )
    return document_db
```

which I want to tested with pytest and mocking.
How it is possible to mock insert_one and find_one function?

I sent conn as a MagicMock and AsyncMock, but I got error

```
TypeError: object MagicMock can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: Have you tried to look into `mongomock`?

Comment: Yes, and doesn't work https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/issues/244